# Homework: Hessenberg, Givens matrix calculations QR

Tags: matrices, transformation

I have been trying to figure out for the past 2 hours and I have to say I give up. My last resort is that maybe someone will have time to explain this to me.

The task is to calculate matrix A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    12 & 65 & 65 \\
    3 & 13 & 0 \\
    -4 & 0 & 13
\end{bmatrix}

1. Into Hessenberg matrix A'.
2. Find QR factorization for A' matrix using Givens rotations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's an inverse matrix

Comment: Well, all of them I guess. But this homework is passed due already and I passed :) Not sure if I can close this question as irrelevant somehow.